# IBOutlets are nil when dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier method is called? Call goes to awakeFromNib but even after super call IBOutlets are nil

Tags: ios, swift

- CollectionViewCell is registered with the same name as used for identifier.
- I checked the IBOutlets and they are connected to file and also, xib's file owner is also correct.

Comment: do you access your `IBOutlet` in after `dequeue` them in `CellForRowAt` like `cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named:"foo")` something like this ?

Comment: try to `ctrl` + `click` your outlet on the **IB** and double check how they're connected to the class and under what name.

Answer (score 0):

While you are accessing **IBoutlets** of cell in your **cellForRow** method, make sure you **unrap** the cell after calling **dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier** method.